# Was Inspector Villiers part of the cover-up conspiracy at East Proctor?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, an-american-werewolf-in-london

David Kessler and Jack Goodman are attacked by a werewolf after leaving a pub called *The Slaughtered Lamb* in *East Proctor*.

The people of East Proctor are attempting to keep a secret from the rest of the world that their village has an inhabitant of a werewolf.  The people let David and Jack leave the pub knowing full well that they would likely be attacked.   After realizing this was a mistake, the villagers find David and Jack AFTER Jack was killed and David was being attacked.  The villagers killed the werewolf.  The villagers of East Proctor then brought David to the hospital and reported that the boys were attacked by an escaped lunatic since the werewolf returned to human form after it was killed.

While David is recovering in the hospital from the wounds that he received from the attack on the moors, Inspector Villiers and Sergeant McManus interview him regarding the attack.

David is adamant that he and his friend, Jack were attacked by a werewolf and NOT an escaped lunatic as the villagers from East Proctor told the police.  Sergeant McManus wants to listen to David's story, but Inspector Villiers is hesitant to listen to his story and does not want to investigate the matter further.

**Is there any evidence to suggest that Inspector Villiers was a part of the conspiracy at East Proctor to cover up the attack?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Was Inspector Villiers part of the cover-up conspiracy at East Proctor?**

I don't think so. He just seems to be a practical person who don't believe in this werewolf mumbo jumbo. It's never addressed in the film that he got any hands in the coverup. Even Jack Goodman  was equally unaware.

**Is there any evidence to suggest that Inspector Villiers was a part of the conspiracy at East Proctor to cover up the attack?**

If he really know that fact, he would have gone with preparation. He lost his life in final confrontation and seems equally shock and ill prepared.

If he really know about werewolf truth, he should have gone fully prepared.